# Why won't my Enter Key Events in WPF C# do anything?

Tags: c#, wpf

My enter key events won't do anything...not even show a simple textbox when pressing Enter in a textbox.

I am new to c# and coding in general.

Interestingly, my visual studio won't let some things go through like MessageBox.Show... It makes me do System.Windows.MessageBox.Show.  Just in case this is a clue to what the problem may be...

Here is what I have...

```
private void textBoxPartNumber_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Enter)
        {
            //textBoxQuantity.Focus();
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Testing 123");
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");                
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: check your xaml binding for this event

Comment: Your question requests help with a WPF app, but your code uses namespaces from a windows forms app. Which one are you using?

Comment: That's a good question.  I know it was WPF Application when I first started it as a new project, but I have no idea how I could check it now, but like I said, I used to have things like MessageBox.Show, but visual studio wouldn't let me do that so I pressed ctrl+. and let it fix itself.

Comment: Yes! The binding was the issue.  I did not even realize you have to reference the PreviewKeyDown or KeyDown event handlers just like the Click="" things.  I'm far from a pro.  Now, I have to figure out why the SendKeys or SendWait won't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using WPF then it appears your event signature is incorrect.  Try something like this:

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

The `KeyEventArgs` class and `Key` enum are in the `System.Windows.Input` namespace in the `PresentationCore` assembly.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I did have Key before, but it would not do anything, so I searched on Google and tried KeyCode not realizing it was for winforms then ended up just posting that here.  Between your comment and Mostafiz's I was able to get the if to show a MessageBox if I hit enter/return, but I can't get it to send a Tab key or any other key. 

Any idea why System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("test"); works but System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}"); doesn't?

If I have both of them on at the same time though, the messagebox comes up 2 times in a row...

Comment: I achieved the desired effect by instead of sending keys just saying textbox2.Focus();

     Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

TextBox property AcceptsReturn

```
<TextBox AcceptsReturn="true"/>
```

Comment: This just makes it so I can press enter within the textbox instead of executing a new command to change boxes.

Comment: Well did you test it?

Comment: Oh, I figured out the fix.  Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I actually tried that in the IDE in the properties when I was trying everything I could think of by exploring before I came here to ask.  I just tested it again, and it does the same thing: It just hits enter within the textBox and goes to a new line inside the box.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if (e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Return)
```

Instead :)

Comment: This doesn't give me any red squigglies, but it still won't do anything when I give it a carriage return either.